# Global Settings iOS Auto time

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

It´s possible, detect with Swift or Objective-C if in the settings Date & Time, "Set Automatically" is enabled ???

In android there is "Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME_ZONE", I am looking  a equivalent in Swift/Objective-C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this given the standard SDK. There are jailbroken/private API methods, but I would not recommend relying on them.

If your goal is to keep someone from going back in the past (to circumvent some kind of timed trial) you could store the *most recent* date you've seen (maybe at startup) in the `NSUserDefaults`, and if at any time you notice that the *current* time is more than one hour earlier than the *most recently stored* time, you can probably safely assume the user has manually changed their time.

But without knowing *why* you want to do this, it's difficult to offer better suggestions.